# Can I install Firefox addons on Tor Browser?

Tags: windows, firefox, add-on

I want to begin to use Tor Browser (on Windows) but before I need to know some issues. I have read Tor's six pillars and one of that is "Don't enable or install browser plugins". So my doubt is: *does it include "normal" add-ons?*

With "normal" addons I refer to extensions like Diigo Extension, Buffer, Zotero, Color Picker... I need some of them to work and improve my self-management.

Everything I have read is about **plugins**: VLC, RealPlayer, Flash, Java... But nothing about Firefox Add-ons.

Comment: From the perspective of using them in Tor, I don't think there's any distinction between a _plugin_ and an _addon_. In the least, they will **all** reduce your anonymity by adding to your browser's fingerprint. The general recommendation is to not use them. Have a read of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/how-can-i-check-if-a-firefox-plugin-is-a-deanonymization-threat?rq=1

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help @RichardHorrocks.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks: See [the answer](http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/9483/9411). Plugins are easily detectable (as of SuperUser link), addons not so. Please reply if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - it does appear that add-ons are difficult to detect :) I'd still recommend against them, even if not because of the fingerprinting issue. If the add-on isn't open source, you have know way to know what the code might be doing, which could include revealing your IP address.

Comment: It seems to me that Tor can produce addons themselves, or at least thoroughly analyze the existing ones, and provide the community with a list of approved addons that do not undermine the service provided. Is there no discussion about this?

Comment: Hi, it's best if you ask questions as new questions rather than posting them as an answer. But the two problems generally are (1) not enough people and time, and (2) having different extensions can make your [browser fingerprint](https://www.avast.com/c-what-is-browser-fingerprinting) different from other Tor Browser users.

Comment: I would have, but then you would have criticized me for asking a repeat question of one thats already been asked.  You cant win on stackexchange; there is always a troll lurking in the corner to criticize and shut you down. And you provided such a simple answer do you really think it would have been worthwhile to create a whole new question for?

Comment: The real question now is how and why do extensions effect a "browser fingerprint"? Why must they? Cant they be programmed not to?  If every tor browser had them installed by default then they wouldnt uniquely identify anyone, would they? If it operated on the client side only then how could it leave fingerprints on the internet? And if there are such exceptions, if they can be designed... then those are the ones I was talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The worst thing that can happen is that the add-on tries to access the internet and doesn't use Tor.
**--> that will destroy your anonymity and release your real IP address!**

Hopefully the worst thing will not happen, but what definitely happens is that you(r browser) will get more trackable with every additional add-on!

---

Here are some tests to see how unique your profile is and what can/will be tracked:

- [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)
- [IP check](http://ip-check.info/?lang=en)
- [BrowserLeaks](https://www.browserleaks.com/)

...to be really save i would suggest to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)!
the related FAQ of Tails about this topic: ["Can I install other add-ons in Tor Browser?"](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index12h2)

Comment: It's not about quantity of add-ons - it's possible to have 1000 normal add-ons and be untracked, but you can have just one bad quality one - and you're owned.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin that i wanted to say with the first abstract... but with more and more add-ons the possibility increases that you got one "bad" add-on! -- and well... people who check every add-on before installing, won't ask such a question! **;-)**

Comment: Actually there's a relatively short list of must-have add-ons, so it's not so difficult to check them all

Answer (score 3):

As of https://superuser.com/questions/137931/can-websites-see-my-firefox-addons, **there is no default API to detect addons, [as there is for plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins)**. As [stated](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/8848/9411), malicious addons can certainly decloak you, but normal, heavily-used addons should have received some vetting, so should be a bit more trustworthy.

I have not examined the addons you listed, though.

Comment: "addons can not be detected by default" is slightly misleading. There is no API that reports installed addons, like there is for plugins but many addons will affect the *behaviour* of the browser and due to this those can be detected.

Comment: @canonizingironize: hopefully slightly less misleading now. Nice writeup at github, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that whether you use plugins or addons, many of them perform background operations communicating with remote servers. Unless you know exactly where the traffic is going and coming from as well as the transport layer being used to transmit and receive the data associated with the plugin or addon, you can't be sure that what is passing to and from your system is being channeled through tor and the corresponding relays. Without knowing all of that, it's best to keep the plugin and addon usage down to a minimum if using at all.  I would recommend to refrain from using any while navigating with/through tor, and revisit where you can later with the standard browser when not connected through the tor network if you want or need to used any plugins or addons.  Of course that would exclude any tor specific network locations such as .onion sites, but I'm sure you'd hate to expose yourself when you're trying to be anonymous. It's definitely a sticky situation, but always better to exercise caution when unsure (aka better safe than sorry). Some of the comments above are really useful such as reviewing a short list of must-have add-ons to keep them down to a minimum and to know that they are safe. ~RM

Comment: "Some of the comments above are really useful such as reviewing a short list of must-have add-ons to keep them down to a minimum and to know that they are safe." Was there a link to see what add on suggestions those may be? Thanks!