# Tor Browser - Keep Cookies for select websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cookies

I am using Tor Browser to do research work and I use a lot Google.

Is it possible to keep Google Cookie intact between Tor Browser restarts?

I know it's quite complicated problem so that's why I am asking because I am not sure about consequences of changing various settings as well installing extra add-ons. But I think maybe I should just disable Private Mode and install add-on for cookie whitelist? Would that compromise Tor Privacy?

Comment: why do you use Tor when you consider disabling private mode?!? -- concerning your idea installing additional add-on(s): https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/can-i-install-firefox-addons-on-tor-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to keep cookies, it is not recommended because it can make your privacy void.

When you keep cookies out of the Tor Browser's sandbox, you are letting these cookies send your real IP address to the website and therefore you can be tracked pretty easily.

This can result in ad targeting, for example keep showing you ads for your research, or if you go into deep / dark web, you can get into prison easily just because they found your real IP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You have to disable "Always use private browsing mode" from `Options->privacy & Security` or simply this link: `about:preferences#privacy`

Then It'll be just like a normal browser with some privacy settings. For example, in the same page you have to change "Keep until" to "they expire", etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. It's the same as Firefox settings, since Tor browser is based on Firefox ESR.

**It is, however, highly *not* recommended.** That would create *serious* privacy issues, and probably circumvent Tor privacy entirely.

If cookies are that big of a concern to you, I'd recommend using those sites in another browser than Tor. Tor's entire purpose is untraceable and privacy. Cookies are, well, traces of what you've done.