# How to bring back the default Firefox start page?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

By default, Tor Browser 8.0 offers its own home page "about:tor" with DuckDuckGo search bar, version indicator, get started guide and other useless things. It would be great to replace it with the default Firefox start page "about:home" with its convenient TOP SITES menu (a.k.a. speed dial), but unfortunately it seems to be permanently disabled by developers. Third-party extensions, such as open sourced [New Tab Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/) and [Metro tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/metro-tab/) also don't work properly: for some reason they cannot load thumbnails. Is there any way to solve the speed dial problem in the Tor Browser somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. having a special `about:tor` is intended and the *"convenient TOP SITES"* are THANKFULLY disabled by the developers.
2. DON'T install any additional addons: [Can I install Firefox addons on Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/8832/5234)
3. i don't know how the addons fetch their thumbnails (or connect to the internet), but the internal function pings the sites regularly and with this special (personal) set of sites and the temporal correlation it may be possible to track you!
4. so if there is something like a *"speed dial problem"*, it is already solved by the tor-devs!

now it is your decision to either use a convenient browser with bells, whistles and every thing else like tracking or a secure browser with audited code, secure addons and carefully chosen default settings.