# Will Privacy Possum in Firefox equal the Tor Browser for anonymity?

Tags: firefox

Privacy Possum is a plugin for the Firefox Browser is it equal to the Tor Browser for anonymity?

Answer (score 2):

1. **NO!**
   Tor hides your IP address and this addon does not.
2. do **NOT** change (especially install additional) addons in Tor Browser!
   [Can I install Firefox addons on Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/8832/5234)

Comment: This question is about using Privacy Possum in Firefox not Tor Browser. But thanks for the warning anyways!