# IDM Integration

Tags: add-on

I was trying to download some videos which are restricted in my country. Sometimes there are some websites which are also restricted. I tried to integrate IDM into th ToR Browser. I failed. Is there any way I can do it?

Is there any other video downloader for ToR especially?

Comment: see https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/8832/5234

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should *NOT* use any add-ons in Tor, except for those that are included it Tor Browser (such as NoScript, HTTPSEverywhere and other privacy related add-ons).
[This answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/15407/17825) by user [HoundCat](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/16936/houndcat) explains it really well:

> Just keep in mind that whether you use plugins or addons, many of them
>   perform background operations communicating with remote servers.
>   Unless you know exactly where the traffic is going and coming from as
>   well as the transport layer being used to transmit and receive the
>   data associated with the plugin or addon, you can't be sure that what
>   is passing to and from your system is being channeled through tor and
>   the corresponding relays. Without knowing all of that, it's best to
>   keep the plugin and addon usage down to a minimum if using at all. I
>   would recommend to refrain from using any while navigating
>   with/through tor, and revisit where you can later with the standard
>   browser when not connected through the tor network if you want or need
>   to used any plugins or addons. Of course that would exclude any tor
>   specific network locations such as .onion sites, but I'm sure you'd
>   hate to expose yourself when you're trying to be anonymous. It's
>   definitely a sticky situation, but always better to exercise caution
>   when unsure (aka better safe than sorry). Some of the comments above
>   are really useful such as reviewing a short list of must-have add-ons
>   to keep them down to a minimum and to know that they are safe.

Answer (score 1):

As I realized, the sites does not allow scripts to be loaded. A suggestion:
Use a normal browser which enables JavaScript with TOR. For example, while TOR Browser is running, start a FireFox and set SOCKS proxy in FireFox which does not have the TOR Browser restrictions.
[image: FireFox proxy Settings with TOR Browser]

But if the site bans TOR IP (Such as what Google does), check out the [integration of TOR + VPN](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-again/) in my blog.