# Is OurStickys addon safe to use with TOR?

Tags: add-on

I am aware that in general installing addons in TOR is not recommended but OurStickys addon seems like a basic (and very useful) addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ourstickys/

The privacy details in "About this extension" is very clear:
"Privacy is very important to us. We do not store any sensitive information and we make sure that the information is not accessible by anyone. No third party web application, nowhere to register, nobody to trust your data with.
NO DATA in any form will be shared with anyone."

Although the privacy policy web page is not opening! http://ourstickys.com/privacy.html

So, is it safe to install OurStickys addon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Firefox addons on Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/can-i-install-firefox-addons-on-tor-browser)

Answer (score 0):

**NO!**
and this has nothing to do with a *privacy policy* or loading resp. not loading websites!
nowadays nearly every website, app, etc. does have somewhere a statement, that they "care about privacy", but then most of them act against it either by accident or very deliberately.

and regarding Tor it is not (primarily) about preventing someone to collect your data, but about not revealing your IP address **AND** also not being anyhow else traceable by standing out with your profile/settings/addons/etc.
...thereby making eventually collected data more or less useless because they cannot be linked to anyone.

the question about this with further information & links: [Can I install Firefox addons on Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/can-i-install-firefox-addons-on-tor-browser)

---

in case of this particular addon i would be careful because of...

1. the permissions it needs: [*"Access your data for all websites"*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permission-request-messages-firefox-extensions#w_access-your-data-for-all-websites) sounds not very "basic" to me!
2. beside that it seems to be an abandoned addon, because it didn't receive any update since nearly 2 years (although mid 2017 it got updates every month) and the complete domain - not just the privacy policy - seems to be down.

i strongly recommend to not install this addon (certainly not in the TorBrowser - i wouldn't even install it in my "normal" browser) and use the normal bookmark-function to add some notes to an URL.

Comment: The normal bookmark-function in Tor browser 8.5 (Firefox 60.7.0 ESR) (64 bit) Linux does not have an option to add notes directly to a URL as only tags field is available for editing directly (via bookmark icon) in which only a few characters can be saved. For adding more text, I have to bookmark a site, right-click the bookmark, select properties and then edit the description, hence no direct option is available. If one has structured bookmarks within folders then adding and viewing notes from the bookmarks is very cumbersome.