# How am I anonymous and safe with my config?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, transparent-proxy, openbsd

I have got ThinkPad T400 with coreboot and minimal OpenBSD installation with full-disk encryption. All non-Tor traffic is dropped by pf. Only allowed traffic on the host is torified traffic from package manager, gpg, git and traffic from virtual machines. I set up Whonix-Workstation inside virtual machine and Whonix-Gateway on separate device. ThinkPad works without battery on AC power. I use open-hardware router. Is it a good setup for anonymous using internet?

Answer (score 0):

As far as it goes it sound good.

Make sure that you follow the projects recommendations for browser settings.  There are also various add-ons that can both increase anonymity and make the browser more useful.

If you install any other software, make sure that you have done a search on the "make and model" to verify that it has not been hacked.  To be truthful I would not add any software that has not been vetted by the project in some manner.

Comment: i strongly advise against installing addons in Tor Browser on your own: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/8832/5234