# How do I enable plugins so I can use Tor to see sites that require plugins, and how do i prevent IP leak?

Tags: plugin, add-on, firewall

If a firewall is a good idea, where/how do i need to set up a firewall? (Sorry i'm not tech-savvy)

Also i noticed firefox has an addon for preventing webrtc ip leaks.
Can that be used with tor?

Comment: Getting pretty tired of people asking multiple questions, all of which are duplicates but you can only flag it as a duplicate of one. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: If you're not tech savvy, don't try to setup your own firewall. Use a pre-existing solution. Plugins can be enabled by going into the Tor Button privacy and security settings and WebRTC support isn't included in Tor Browser (and hasn't been for a long time). However enabling plugins and using a firewall won't stop all forms of IP leaks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a Firefox plugin is a deanonymization threat?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/how-can-i-check-if-a-firefox-plugin-is-a-deanonymization-threat)

Answer (score 1):

You prevent IP leaks by using the tor browser bundle in its most paranoid security setting.

Enabling plugins will expose you to deanonymouzation techniques. Enabling a firewall does not help.

The reason the defaults are the way they are is for your safety. Do not change them unless you understand the consequences.