# Is anyone maintaining a list of "Tor-vetted" browser add-ons?

Tags: firefox, add-on

I want to use my Tor Browser with some of my addons (e.g. avoiding Ads). I just read

[How can I check if a Firefox plugin is a deanonymization threat?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1225/14165)

and understood it is difficult for *me* as a user to check add-ons/plugins. But what about other people/groups? Are there lists of browser add-ons (not plugins) considered safe or "safe enough"? Of course, many of these would also have a list of necessary settings (such as "disable logging", "do not report usage statistics", "do not check for XYZ online" etc.)

I'm specifically interested in Firefox.

Comment: Actually, the Tor Browser considers all add-ons unsafe. Ad Blockers for example will change how your browser loads websites, and break anonymity. But if you're using Tor for extra security, say on a public WiFi, it might not matter to you.

Comment: There are probably some extensions that don't actually affect browser behaviour in ways an external attacker could be inferred by a remote party but other concerns should also for anti-forensic properties. Is it doing anything that might result in your browsing activity being logged to disk. (I've seen some adblockers wanting to count blocked elements for example...what if a specific element only appears on one site and your adblocker logged that it blocked it?). tl;dr it's non-trivial and theres no guarantee that the behaviour of an extension will not change unexpectedly in the future.

Comment: @SuperSluether: Anonymity will also be broken by, say, cookies, or my pattern of triggering certain beacons on the site. So I'm not sure I buy that argument.

Comment: @canonizingironize: Of course, logging would need to be turned off. See edit.

Comment: @einpoklum I see your point. Last time I tried to make a point like that, I was told I didn't understand how one is supposed to use Tor.